# Is that possible to generate correct indenting code with nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

When i'm generating the project with nuxtjs, the code is compressed.

I would like to know if it's possible to generate a correct indenting code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The minimization is done by Webpack. You can change the [Webpack config](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/extend-webpack) in your `nuxt.config.js` file under the `extend` option of the `build` property. To disable minimization, you need to set `config.optimization.minimize` to `false`.

For example, in your `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
        config.optimization.minimize = false;
    }
  },
```

You probably wouldn't want to do this in production though. Minimization is a [standard practice](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/performance/why-minify-javascript-code/) to help reduce the size of your JavaScript files.